# Load view/controller programmatically

Tags: angularjs

How do I, at runtime, load a view / controller?

Say for example I have a list of content like so

```
ctrl.pages = [{
  controller:"myController",
  templateUrl : "/app/view.html"
},{
  controller:"myController2",
  templateUrl : "/app/view2.html"
}]
```

How do I then load those views and controllers? Is it simply just a case of using "ng-include" or is there a better way? Libraries such as Angular Material dont seem to do it this way.

```
<ng-include ng-repeat="page in ctrl.pages" 
            ng-controller="{{page.controller}}"
            src="{{page.templateUrl }}"></ng-include>
```

Comment: Haven't you heard about angular ui-routing?

Comment: Yes, and I'm using it but what if I don't want to use it for this specific thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like either a case for a template expanding directive, see the Angular docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).  Or if those pages represent different "states" of the application, somewhere a user might visit directly via a URL, they'd be a good candidate for [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

Answer (score 1):

check this [plnk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uwU3OlR3E4dhggJ2Fy5z?p=preview) out.

I added a `select` of available views and based on the selection `ng-include`'s `src` is updated.

I avoided initializing the `controller`(s) intentionally, you may include them.